# how to access the asp.net application with QTP

Tags: qtp

[image]i have asp.net application, test that application using QTP descriptive code , but i am getting error

> Cannot find the "[ WebEdit ]" object's parent "[ Page ]" (class Page). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.
>      Line (8): ".WebEdit("Page:=txtUserName").Set "raju"".

my code is

```
    Systemutil.Run("http://some ip/login.aspx")   
With Browser("creationtime:=0")
    With .page("title:=.*")
        With  .WebTable("Name:=log_left,")
            With .WebTable("Name:=leaf")
                    With .WebTable("Name:=txtUserName","Index:=0")
                            .WebEdit("Name:=txtUserName").Set "raju"
                                    .WebEdit("Name:=txtPassword").Set "raju"
                                        .WebButton("Name:=Button").Click
                    End With
                End With
                End With
            End With
            End With
```

now also i have same problem, object spy shows 3 tables, which table i want to use and which property i want to use in that table.please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have multiple problems with your test.
The first problem which is currently blocking you is the description of the `Page` object. `Page` *does* support the **name** identification property but I suspect that it doesn't have the value *Page* (perhaps you meant to use `micclass:=Page`).

Since a `Browser` can only have on `Page` object at any time it's customary to use a more inclusive description, something like `"title:=.*` (descriptive programming uses regular expressions by default so `.*` means anything).

Once you fix that problem you will be faced with QTP's inability to identify the `WebTable`, `WebEdit` and `WebButton` test objects. None of these objects support a **Page** identification property, perhaps you meant to write **name** or **html id**?

In any case you should use the object spy in order to see what properties test objects support and what value the specific test object has.

Comment: thank u for reply, i modified my question please verify it and give me suggestion

Comment: You don't have to have the `WebTable`s at all, try removing them. Also try using a test with an object repository rather than descriptive programming and then if you really need descriptive programming look at the description from the repository to see what description to use in the descriptive programming.